# Context for JPA AttributeConverter

Tags: java, jpa

I am using a JPA AttributeConverter to encrypt Strings that are stored in the database. Something very similar to what is proposed at:
http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-use-jpa-type-converter-to/

However, that example has the Key created inside the converter:

```
@Converter
public class CryptoConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
private static final byte[] KEY = "MySuperSecretKey".getBytes();

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String ccNumber) {
  // do some encryption
  Key key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES");
  try {
     Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
     c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
     return Base64.encodeBytes(c.doFinal(ccNumber.getBytes()));
  } catch (Exception e) {
     throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}

@Override
public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
  // do some decryption
  Key key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES");
  try {
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    return new String(c.doFinal(Base64.decode(dbData)));
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
}
```

My key (and other parts of the encryption) depend on other state. This state isn't part of the AttributeConverter interface, so can't be passed in.

What is the best way to store this (per-request) state so that the AttributeConverter can access it?

Thanks.

Comment: CDI may help you. Provide the needed objects with a producer.

Comment: share your code so that we have a look on it to help you.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever solve this?

Comment: @thehpi Sorry, no. I ended up changing my application to not use an Attribute Converter.

Comment: I actually was able to `@Inject` a `@RequestScoped` bean which contains the state. This then can be used in the encryption algorithm. The drawback is however that when this is done in a different thread that you loose the state. So use with care. Microprofile is however working on this: https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-context-propagation/